# OnClick method in own component works slow

Tags: c#, events

i'm trying to make my own component, which I will use to change background. Now  I have really empty component form, and i put it on the form. To onclick event I add a code:

```
 private void myComponent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = (this.BackColor == Color.Red) ? Color.Blue : Color.Red;
    }
```

It works when i click slow. But when i'm clicking very fast, background is changing always on the second click. What is wrong in this code? I tried too use MouseClick, but there is the same result.

Comment: Try handling the doubleclick event as well. (And overriding OnClick is the recommended way of handling events in your own components.)

Comment: Are you handling any paint events yourself? Have you overridden `BackColor`?

Answer (score 0):

On clicking fast you may be having `DoubleClick` instead of `Click`.

Handle `DoubleClick` event as well.

example:

```
 private void userControl11_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BackColor = (this.BackColor == Color.Red) ? Color.Blue : Color.Red;
        }

        private void userControl11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BackColor = (this.BackColor == Color.Red) ? Color.Blue : Color.Red;
        }
```

Comment: so when doubleClick appears, Click doesn't work twice? How can I solve my problem?